# Software to disable multi-key presses to prevent "fat finger" typos

Tags: windows, keyboard, accessibility

Background: my hands, especially the left one, are fairly seriously disabled due to spinal cord damage and I can only use a keyboard with my two index fingers, plus the right thumb for pressing space, the middle finger for backspace and the ring finger for return.

My hands shake quite a bit, and one of the most bothersome consequences of this is that I make a lot of "fat finger" typos (even though my fingers are very thin!) because instead of hitting on a key I hit between two keys, and of course they both get registered by the OS.

Now, Windows has got a lot of accessibility features but disabling this behavior seems not to be among them. It can disable or slow down the repeat rate of the *same* key and it can force the user to press a key for a (not very) configurable time before it gets accepted, but I haven't seen anything to prevent fat finger mistakes.

Is there any software that can do this, preferably disabling the multiple key press feature only for pairs of keys that are actually next to each other on the keyboard (if such a thing can be done)?